# git 1.7.1: use custom configuration file located in local directory

Tags: git, configuration

I am trying to specify a proxy for a "git clone" command. I see that git 1.8.3.2 has the "-c" option for specifying configuration parameters. The system I am on has git 1.7.1, which doesn't have this option.

I have figured out how to create a custom configuration file with "git config --file". However, I cannot figure out how to tell git to use the configuration in this file.

I need this custom configuration file to be in a local folder. I don't have a home directory on this system, so I can't put it in the standard "~/.gitconfig" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In git 1.7.1 there was still the GIT_CONFIG shell variable but I remember that it was only applicable to running `git config`, so it won't suit you.

What you should do instead is set the `HOME` environment variable, so git will be able to locate your custom `$HOME/.gitconfig`.

For example, you can set it in a sub-shell so it won't affect any subsequent commands.

```
bash $ (HOME=/your/path/to/git/config git pull)
```

This is not very practical to do every time you want to run a git command, so you will probably have to setup a shell function as a shortcut, along the following lines:

```
bash $ function git() { (HOME=/your/path/to/git/config; command git $*;) };
```

When the function is setup, your next git commands, will be run in a sub-shell with the right environment set:

```
bash $ git pull // executes the function above and forwards the argument to git
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. It surprises me that git didn't have a command-line argument to set configuration parameters until a later version. The solution seems kind of hacky, but I guess not unnecessarily so.